# How can i store array first value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have created and stored on JSON file in array like the below.

```
store = [{ "name" : "guido van rossum", "language" : "python"}, {"name" : "james gosling", "language" : "java"}]
```

the below command is used for complete array stored.

```
db.collection.insert(store)
```

Now i need to store first value of array only like guido van rossum and python only.

So how can i store only array first value???

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Access first element of the array `[0]` like this : `db.collection.insert(store[0])`